# Error message when running NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve a set of differential equations but keep getting an error. See message below

> "NDSolveValue::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t=0"

The system that I am trying to solve is the following:

```
e=.16 
g=.4 
w=.97
```

I set it up as follows:

```
sol=NDSolveValue[{y1'[t]==y2[t],y2'[t]==-((2/L[t]) L'[t]+g L[t]) y2[t]-(1/L[t]) Sin[y1[t]],L'[t]==7 e w Sin^6[w t+9 pi/8] Cos[w t+ 9 pi/8],y1[0]==-1,y2[0]==1},y1[t],y2[t],L[t]},{t,0,30}] 

ParametricPlot[{y1[t],y2[t]},{t,0,30},AxesLabel->{"y1[t]","y2[t]"}]
```

Comment: hi, user41071, can you check the line with NDSolve? It doesn't seem correct to me, but I didn't want to edit it and get it completely wrong.

Comment: It should also be `NDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolvevalue`. Note the capital "V".

Comment: hi, user41071, you forgot a initial condition for `L[t]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
e = .16;
g = .4;
w = .97;
```

You must add a initial condition, assume: `L[0]=1`

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y1'[t] == y2[t], 
y2'[t] == -((2/L[t]) L'[t] + g L[t]) y2[t] - (1/L[t]) Sin[y1[t]], 
L'[t] == 7 e w Sin[w t + 9 Pi/8]^6* Cos[w t + 9 Pi/8], 
y1[0] == -1, y2[0] == 1, L[0] == 1}, {y1, y2, L}, {t, 0, 30}];

ParametricPlot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
AxesLabel -> {"y1[t]", "y2[t]"}]
```

[image]